# How do I call a controller function from a template in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

Let's say I have a template which iterates over a collection of items, and I want to call a function with each item which is specific to the controller, and not a model-level concern:

```
{{#each people as |person|}}
  icon name: {{findIconFor(person)}}
{{/each}}
```

I'd like to define `findIconFor` in the controller, because this is something specific to this particular view.

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  findIconFor: function(person) {
    // figure out which icon to use
  }
);
```

**But that doesn't work.**  The template fails to compile.  Parse error: *Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'ID', 'DATA', got 'INVALID'*

What is the "ember way" to do this?

Comment: Well, you can't do that, because you can't do that. You could put a computed property on `person`, then just do `person.icon`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd use a computed property in the controller:

```
iconPeople: Ember.computed('people.@each', function(){
  var that = this;
  return this.get('people').map(function(person){
    return {
      'person': person,
      'icon': that.findIconFor(person)
    };
  });
})
```

Now you could get the icon from `{{person.icon}}` and the name from `{{person.person.name}}`. You might want to improve on that (and the code is untested), but that's the general idea.

Comment: Oh, sorry, yes. I've changed it accordingly.

Comment: Why "people.@each" and not "people"?

Comment: You want to listen to changes not only of the people array itself (i.e. a different array) but also on contents oft the array.

Answer (score 15):

As i spent almost entire day on a similar problem here is my solution.

Because Ember for some reason just doesn't allow you to run a controller functions directly from the template (which is ridiculous and ties your hands in some very stupid ways and i don't know who on earth decided this is a good idea ...) the thing that makes most sense to me is to create an universal custom helper, that allows you to run functions from the template :) The catch here is that you should always pass the current scope (the "this" variable) to that helper.

So the helper could be something like this:

```
export default Ember.Helper.helper(function([scope, fn]) {
    let args = arguments[0].slice(2);
    let res = fn.apply(scope, args);
    return res;
});
```

Then, you can make a function inside your controller, that you want to run, for example:

```
testFn: function(element){
    return element.get('name');
}
```

and then in your template you just call it with the custom helper:

```
{{#each items as |element|}}
    {{{custom-helper this testFn element}}}
{{/each}}
```

The first two arguments to the helper should always be "this" and the name of the function, that you want to run, and then you can pass as many extra  arguments as you wish.

---

Edit: Anyway, every time when you think you need to do this, you should think if it will not be better to create a new component instead (it will be in 90% of the cases)

Comment: Just typo, but I think {{{custom-helper this testFn element}}} have one bracket too much on each side

Comment: actually not a typo, the "triple-stash" means "do not escape HTML tags", but  you can do it also with 2 brackets

Comment: "which is ridiculous and ties your hands in some very stupid ways..." A voice to my frustrations. Seems like a simple thing a framework should handle.

Comment: Same feelings here bro :( .

Answer (score 1):

If the icon is something associated with a person, then since the person is represented by a model, it is best to implement it as a computed property on the person model. What is your intent in trying to put it into the controller?

```
// person.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  icon: function() { return "person-icon-" + this.get('name'); }.property('name')
  ..
};
```

Then assuming that `people` is an array of `person`:

```
{{#each people as |person|}}
  icon name: {{person.icon}}
{{/each}}
```

The alternative provided by @jnfingerle works (I assume you figured out that he is proposing that you loop over `iconPeople`), but it seems like a lot of extra work to go to to create a new array containing objects. Does the icon depend on anything known only to the controller? If not, as I said, why should the logic to compute it be in the controller?

Where to put things is a a matter of philosophy and preference. Some people like bare-bones models that contain nothing more than fields coming down from the server; other people compute state and intermediate results in the model. Some people puts lots of stuff in controllers, whereas others prefer light-weight controllers with more logic in "services". Personally, I'm on the side of heavier models, lighter controllers, and services. I'm not claiming that business logic, or heavy data transformations, or view preparations should go in the model, of course. But remember, the model represents an object. If there's some interesting facet to the object, whether it come down from the server or be computed somehow, to me it makes a lot of sense to put that in the model.

Remember also that controllers are part of a tightly-coupled route/controller/view nexus. If there's some model-specific thing that you compute in one controller, you might have to then add it to some other controller that happens to be handling the same model. Then before you know it you're writing controller mixins that share logic across controllers that shouldn't have been in them in the first place.

Anyway, you say your icon comes from an "unrelated data store". That sounds asynchronous. To me, that hints that maybe it's a sub-model called `PersonIcon` which is a `belongsTo` in the `person` model. You can make that work with the right mix of adapters and serializers for that model. The nice thing about that approach is that all the asynchronicity in retrieving the icon is going to be handled semi-magically, either when the `person` model is created, or when you actually need the icon (if you say `async: true`).

But perhaps you're not using Ember Data, or don't want to go to all that trouble. In that case, you could consider adorning the person with the icon in the route's model hook, making use of Ember's ability to handle asynchronous model resolution, by doing something like the following:

```
model: function() {
  return this.store.find('person') .
    then(function(people) {
      return Ember.RSVP.Promise.all(people.map(getIcon)) .
        then(function(icons) {
          people.forEach(function(person, i) {
            person.set('icon') = icons[i];
          });
          return people;
        })
      ;
    })
  ;
}
```

where `getIcon` is something like

```
function getIcon(person) {
  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    $.ajax('http://icon-maker.com?' + person.get('name'), resolve);
  });
}
```

Or, if it is cleaner, you could break the icon stuff out into an `afterModel` hook:

```
model: function() { return this.store.find('person'); },

afterModel: function(model) {
  return Ember.RSVP.Promise.all(model.map(getIcon)) .
    then(function(icons) {
      model.forEach(function(person, i) {
        person.set('icon') = icons[i];
      });
    })
  ;
}
```

Now Ember will wait for the entire promise to resolve, including getting the people and their icons and sticking the icons on the people, before proceeding.

HTH.

Comment: The intent is to use some other model data that is in the controller to determine the dynamic result.  This example above is a simple case, but even so, I really don't like putting view-specific concerns on the model.  But in this case, it needs to get the information from an unrelated data store, so it certainly shouldn't be in the model.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but my example here is simple.  In my real case, the data that needs to be correlated with the items is completely unrelated.  Creating relationships for it wouldn't make sense.  The controller has the information it needs to do the correlation, and the model doesn't and shouldn't have this information.  The property approach that @jnfingerle put forward is correct for my needs.  I do wish I could just call a function into the controller.  Seems like a reasonable thing to do.  But that's the Ember way... go off the "rails" a bit, and things get hard.

Comment: It's not the "ember" way, it's the "handlebars" way, to not put logic such as function calls, much less into a controller, into template. In any case, calling the controller from the view/template is a fundamental violation of separation of concerns. You might just as well give up on MVC if you want to do that. The template displays stuff that the controller provides. By the way, can you provide sample code for `getIconFor`? Is it asynchronous or not?

Comment: "calling the controller from the view/template is a fundamental violation of separation of concerns" Then what is an action?  A controller provides data to a view.  A view calls into the controller to delegate behavior.  Controllers and views are always coupled via data contracts and interaction contracts.  A function that exists to provide data for an item seems like a reasonable provision.  It isn't much different than a controller correlating data.  Item controllers would do what I need as well.  But item controllers have been deprecated.

Comment: Haha "you might just give up MVC", Hows? It means .Net and RoR has given up mvc. ? Ideally it should provide the same behavior as the state of the art techs do. I know they are different technologies and domains, but the idea here is the same (MVC). I should be able to do model.somemethod.apply, this.somemethod.apply and the results should be displayed in hbs.