# Rendering <option> inside an #each loop throws error

Tags: templates, components, handlebars.js, ember-cli

I want to dynamically create `<option>` elements inside a `<select>` tag using the following component (based on the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544517/how-do-i-call-a-controller-function-from-a-template-in-ember)) :

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

export default Component.extend({
  computedOptions: computed('optionsList.@each', function() {
    var that = this;
    return this.get('optionsList').map(function(option) {
      let optionIsSelected = option.text === that.selectedElement;
      let builtOption = {
        'option': option,
        'isSelected': optionIsSelected
      };

      return builtOption;
    });
  })
});
```

The `optionsList` and `selectedElement` variables are passed by another component to this one.

In my template, when I use the #each block like this :

```
<select name="{{name}}" id="{{name}}">
    {{#each computedOptions as |option|}}
        <option></option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

I get the following error in my browser's console :

`Error: unreachable` (with the following callstack, if it helps: https://pastebin.com/PkrcAFCr)

I'm not sure what this error means and I don't know why this error happens.

The only way I managed to make this work (somewhat) is by having this template :

```
<select name="{{name}}" id="{{name}}">
    {{#each computedOptions}}
        <option value="{{option.value}}" selected={{option.isSelected}}>{{option.text}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

Removing `as |option|` and using my option properties renders the options without error (3 options in my case), but the options themselves are empty (`<option></option>`) in the resulting HTML, so no text is visible for each option when I click on the select in my page.

Does that mean it's impossible to fill a `<select>` tag dynamically in Ember.js? If it is possible, what is the proper way to do it?

Comment: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/16826 cf my answer

Answer (score 0):

the idea of the `as |something|` is that you can use the variable name you want.

This issue : https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/16826 shows us that there is some conflict when your var name is an existing tag (option, p, etc ...) so you just have to do something like :

```
<select name="{{name}}" id="{{name}}">
  {{#each computedOptions as |opt|}}
    <option value="{{opt.value}}" selected={{opt.isSelected}}>{{opt.text}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```